# Break up a list of strings in a pandas dataframe column into new columns based on first word of each sentence

Tags: python, regex, pandas

So I have roughly 40,000 rows of people and their complaints.  I am attempting to sort them into their respective columns for analysis, and for other analysts 
 at my company who use other tools can use this data.

**DataFrame Example:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"person": [1, 2, 3], 
                   "problems": ["body: knee hurts(bad-pain), toes hurt(BIG/MIDDLE); mind: stressed, tired", 
                                "soul: missing; mind: can't think; body: feels great(lifts weights), overweight(always bulking), missing a finger", 
                                "none"]})
df     
╔═══╦════════╦══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║   ║ person ║                                                     problems                                                     ║
╠═══╬════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 0 ║      1 ║ body: knee hurts(bad-pain), toes hurt(BIG/MIDDLE); mind: stressed, tired                                         ║
║ 1 ║      2 ║ soul: missing; mind: can't think; body: feels great(lifts weights), overweight(always bulking), missing a finger ║
║ 2 ║      3 ║ none                                                                                                             ║
╚═══╩════════╩══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

**Desired Output:**

```
╔═══╦════════╦══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╦════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════╦═══════════════╗
║   ║ person ║                                                     problems                                                     ║                                      body                                      ║         mind          ║     soul      ║
╠═══╬════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 0 ║      1 ║ body: knee hurts(bad-pain), toes hurt(BIG/MIDDLE); mind: stressed, tired                                         ║ body: knee hurts(bad-pain), toes hurt(BIG/MIDDLE)                              ║ mind: stressed, tired ║ NaN           ║
║ 1 ║      2 ║ soul: missing; mind: can't think; body: feels great(lifts weights), overweight(always bulking), missing a finger ║ body: feels great(lifts weights), overweight(always bulking), missing a finger ║ mind: can't think     ║ soul: missing ║
║ 2 ║      3 ║ none                                                                                                             ║ NaN                                                                            ║ NaN                   ║ NaN           ║
╚═══╩════════╩══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╩════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

**Things I've tried / where I'm at:**

So I've been able to at least separate these with a regex statement that seems to do the job with my real data.

```
df.problems.str.extractall(r"(\b(?!(?: \b))[\w\s.()',:/-]+)")


+---+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   |       |                                       0                                        |
+---+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   | match |                                                                                |
| 0 | 0     | body: knee hurts(bad-pain), toes hurt(BIG/MIDDLE)                              |
|   | 1     | mind: stressed, tired                                                          |
| 1 | 0     | soul: missing                                                                  |
|   | 1     | mind: can't think                                                              |
|   | 2     | body: feels great(lifts weights), overweight(always bulking), missing a finger |
| 2 | 0     | none                                                                           |
+---+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'm a regex beginner, so I expect this could probably be done better.  My original regex pattern was `r'([^;]+)'`, but I was trying to exclude the space after the semi-colons.

So I'm at a loss.  I played with:

`df.problems.str.extractall(r"(\b(?!(?: \b))[\w\s.()',:/-]+)").unstack()`, which "works"(doesn't error out) with my example here.

But with my real data, I get an error: `"ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"`

Even if it worked with my real data, I'd still have to figure out how to get these 'categories'(body, mind, soul) into assigned columns.

I'd probably have better luck if I could word this question better.  I'm trying to really self-learn here, so I'll appreciate any leads even if they're not a complete solution.

I'm kind of sniffing a trail that maybe I can do this somehow with a groupby or multiIndex know-how.  Kind of new to programming, so I'm still feeling my way around in the dark.  I would appreciate any tips or ideas anyone has to offer.  Thank you!

EDIT:  I just want to come back and mention the error I was getting in my real data `"ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"` when using @WeNYoBen's solution:

```
(df.problems.str.extractall(r"(\b(?!(?: \b))[\w\s.()',:/-]+)")[0]
.str.split(':',expand=True)
.set_index(0,append=True)[1]
.unstack()
.groupby(level=0)
.first())
```

It turned out I had some groups with multiple colons.  For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"person": [1, 2, 3], 
                   "problems": ["body: knee hurts(bad-pain), toes hurt(BIG/MIDDLE); mind: stressed, energy: tired", 
                                "soul: missing; mind: can't think; body: feels great(lifts weights), overweight(always bulking), missing a finger", 
                                "none"]})




╔═══╦════════╦══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║   ║ person ║                                                     problems                                                     ║
╠═══╬════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 0 ║      1 ║ body: knee hurts(bad-pain), toes hurt(BIG/MIDDLE); mind: stressed, energy: tired                                 ║
║ 1 ║      2 ║ soul: missing; mind: can't think; body: feels great(lifts weights), overweight(always bulking), missing a finger ║
║ 2 ║      3 ║ none                                                                                                             ║
╚═══╩════════╩══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

See the first row update reflecting the edge case I discovered `; mind: stressed, energy: tired`.

I was able to fix this by altering my regex to say the beginning of the match must be the beginning of the string or be preceded with a semi-colon.

```
splits = [r'(^)(.+?)[:]', r'(;)(.+?)[:]']
str.split('|'.join(splits)
```

After that I just had to re-tweak the set_index portion to get @WeNYoBen's helpful solution to work, so I'll stick with this one.

Comment: I should add that yesterday I did figure out how to get the full list of all these groupings in my real data, which is around 10 total.


    `sorted(df.problems.str.extractall(r'(^|;)(.+?)[:]').reset_index()[1].str.strip().unique())`

Comment: Regarding your wanted output: There are some of the `parentheses` missing in the problems column, is that intentional or an oversight? If intentional, on what condition do you want to remove the parentheses?

Comment: Are the three categories always the same?  Body, mind, soul...

Comment: @sobek That's an oversight.  I included later to try and represent my actual data more accurately.  Sorry about that.  I'll update that right now.

Comment: If they are always three category, then you could probably try matching from `body ... ;` and likewise for each category.

Comment: @MartinNoah There's actually 10+ groupings in this problem field.  Anyone has any combination of these, or none at all.

Comment: @ifly6, That .... is an interesting idea.  I'll play with that.  Thanks.

Comment: Good question but should not using lambda with apply

Comment: `df.problems.str.extractall(r"(\b(?!(?: \b))[\w\s.()',:/-]+)")[0].str.split(':',expand=True).set_index(0,append=True)[1].unstack().groupby(level=0).first()
` your own functionafter polish  is better than applt + lambda

Comment: @WeNYoBen This does look better with my example data.  For some reason I'm still getting `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape` on my actual data, which I've been trying to troubleshoot all morning.  Hmm

Comment: Updated my post with the findings / solution to my previous comment.

Comment: @WeNYoBen Don't you want to put your regex solution into an answer? It's probably a lot more performant than what i did...

Comment: @sobek I'm actually using both of your solutions as a stepping stone.  Trying to work out another edge case I discovered where a semi-colon is used within a phrase, just two occurrences out of tens of thousands of rows :/  You guys rock though.  Learned a lot this weekend

Comment: You can sanitize your string of special character `char` before you process them with `str.replace(char, "")` if that is of any help.

Comment: Are you referring to my last edge case?  I beat my head on it for a little bit as a regex learning point, then finally just did a str.replace() since it was just 3 rows, built it into the rest of the function.  Sounds like its along the lines of what you're suggesting, which is a nice sanity check.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not elegant but it gets the job done:

```
df['split'] = df.problems.str.split(';')
df['mind'] = df.split.apply(
    lambda x: ''.join([category for category in x if 'mind' in category]))
df['body'] = df.split.apply(
    lambda x: ''.join([category for category in x if 'body' in category]))
df['soul'] = df.split.apply(
    lambda x: ''.join([category for category in x if 'soul' in category]))
df.drop('split', inplace=True)
```

You could probably wrap

```
df[cat] = df.split.apply(lambda x: ''.join([category for category in x if cat in category]))
```

in a function and run it on your dataframe for each `cat` (e.g. `cats=['mind', 'body', 'soul', 'whathaveyou', 'etc.']`.

---

**Edit**:

As @ifly6 has pointed out, there may be intersections of keywords in the strings that users enter. To be safe, the function should be altered to

```
df[cat] = df.split.apply(lambda x: ''.join([category for category in x if category.startswith(cat)]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I can work with this!  Man I really need to spend time understanding lambda.

Comment: If there's a specific thing you don't understand, ask and i'll try to clarify my answer.

Comment: I appreciate the offer! I'm still so new to programming in general I just need to revisit this from square one.

Comment: What if the string is like "mind: he thinks his body is out of shape"?

Comment: Good point, i didn't consider it because it wasn't in the scope of the test data. I guess it can be solved by using `startswith` instead of `in`.

Comment: That is a really good point.  I might be lucky enough to be able to include a ':' at the end of each term.

`lambda x: ''.join([category for category in x if 'body:' in category`

Comment: Note that I have edited my answer to deal with this edge case (see bottom).